# "Missing right parenthesis" error on CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle SQL, and learning it as we speak. I am wondering what is wrong with my SQL statement. I get a `missing right parenthesis` error:

```
CREATE TABLE hotel(
    hotel_id                number(8)
                            NOT NULL
                            CONSTRAINT hotel_pk
                            PRIMARY KEY,

    user_id                 number(8)
                            NOT NULL,
                            CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),

    hotel_name              varchar2(1024)
                            NOT NULL,

    creation_date           timestamp
                            NOT NULL
                            DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
);
```

Comment: @pcdev It is the exact code

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: Hi Mike, if the answer below was helpful, please upvote and mark as the answer.  This will help others who come looking for answers to your question in future, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma, see comment below:

```
CREATE TABLE hotel(
    hotel_id                number(8)
                            NOT NULL
                            CONSTRAINT hotel_pk
                            PRIMARY KEY,

    user_id                 number(8)
                            NOT NULL -- Comma was here
                            CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),

    hotel_name              varchar2(1024)
                            NOT NULL,

    creation_date           timestamp
                            NOT NULL
                            DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
);
```